How to animate alternating color loop?
I am trying to do something very simple: have an object turn red, blue, red, blue, forever like a police light. It doesn't have to glow. I am using Blender 3.x and Blender 4.x.
I've googled the heck out of this and nothing works! How do you do this?
Thanks!

Plug a Color > Mix Color node into the Base Color of the Principled BSDF and keyframe the factor, then ShiftEt > Make Cyclic or check Lauloque's solution in the comments below:


to not have to make keyframes, you can also write #sin(frame*0.5) in the factor to make a sinusoidal function driver, and change the 0.5 to smaller or bigger values to make the wave slower or faster.

Forgot to mention: you can make it with nodes too: https://i.imgur.com/lNFUgEA.png
